# Multiple Images randomly assign to multiple picture boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am working on windows form where I have 20  `Picturebox` in my winform and 20 images in project folder.
My question is How Can I assign images randomly to Picture boxes.
For Example: On button click - images randomly assign to `Pictureboxs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty straightforward:

1. Get 20 images into an array
2. Shuffle the array
3. Assign images to your PictureBoxes

Assuming that you generate and store your picture boxes in an array, it would look like:

```
string[] shuffledImages = Directory.GetFiles(".", "*.png")
    .OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid())
    .ToArray();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    pictureBoxes[i].Image = Image.FromFile(shuffledImages[i]);
```

Any other changes or improvements are up to you :)

Comment: Interesting, but I wonder: Are GuiD really random wrt to sorting? Unique yes, but totally unsorted?? (Probably ok for 20 items, but what does the theory say??) - A common alternaitve way is to use&remove a random element from the list.)

Comment: Thanks this help me to understand the method.

Comment: @Taw I do not know about the theory, but 10^36+ possible combinations seems to be pretty large number for using this in random sorting. Actually, any "random" sorting is not random :)